# Design notes, interviews, or memoirs identifying the creature on the cover of S3 Expedition to the Barrier Peaks?

Tags: adnd-1e, content-identification

The original cover art of AD&D module *S3 Expedition to the Barrier Peaks* by Erol Otus illustrates a 5-limbed plant-starfish thing battling a party of intrepid adventurers, as excerpted below.

[image: Illustration on the front cover of the AD&D 1st edition module S3 Expedition to the Barrier Peaks]

**What is the illustrated 5-limbed monster?**

For years I had thought this was a *dustdigger* as featured in the AD&D 1st edition *Monster Manual II*, shown below, because so many monsters from *Barrier Peaks* were featured in this book (e.g., *vegepygmy*, *thornies*, *froghemoth*, etc.), and it seemed visually a good match.

[image: Illustration of a Dustdigger from AD&D 1st edition Monster Manual II]

However, a recent perusal of *Barrier Peaks*' bestiary and main text does not include the *dustdigger*.

Any clues from sources outside the module itself?

Answer (score 4):

### You may be making a flawed assumption.

Your baseline assumption here is that Otus's illustration was done with a specific encounter from the module in mind, and was depicting a specific AD&D monster. Neither of these things is necessarily the case. If you look at Otus's cover for *C2 The Ghost Tower of Inverness*, you will see two characters confronting a ghost outside a ghostly tower. In the actual text of the module, there is no ghost (or any other incorporeal undead) that confronts the PCs outside the ghost tower or anywhere else in the module. When Otus drew the cover for C2, it seems highly likely that all he had to go on was the title of the module and had not actually read it--he figured there would be ghosts and a tower. It is just as possible that for S3, he was only told there would be encounters with man-eating plants and the PCs would have access to laser guns. In short, given the difference of appearance between the cover monster and any of the monsters appearing in the module, or any other official AD&D monsters from the time, it is perhaps most likely that Otus was drawing a generic scene with little direct guidance from the text of the module or the AD&D rules.

This is not uncharacteristic of Otus at all. The encounter he depicted on the cover of *L1 Secret of Bone Hill* has no relation to any specific encounter in the module either. The appearance of an animated skeleton might just be because the title of the module contains the word "bone."

### The closest the module comes to this monster is the vampire thorn vine.

The vampire thorn vine at Level IV, [encounter area 16](https://i.4pcdn.org/tg/1456289936292.pdf) is the closest monster appearing in the module to Otus's depiction. It is a plant with a central section and tentacles (described as 5-8 in number). However, Otus's plant's tentacles seem far more akin to octopus tentacles with suckers than the vampire thorn vine's tentacles with blood draining thorns. David S. LaForce's drawing of the vampire thorn vine on page 15 of the module is a far cry from what Otus drew on the cover. It seems unlikely that Otus was specifically trying to depict this monster, though he may have been inspired by a description of the Vampire thorn vine.

### You're probably correct that the dust digger is *not* what Otus was drawing.

The creature on the cover has a clear root system, marking it as a plant. A dust digger is not a plant, but an animal. Despite the similarities, the tentacles appear to be different as well. Further, while many of the monsters in the *MMII* came from earlier modules, many were created for the book itself, and the [dust digger](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Dustdigger) made its first appearance in the 1983 *MMII*. There is no evidence that this monster had even been created when *Expedition to the Barrier Peaks* was written in the 1970s and published in 1980.

### Other sources are elusive.

The kinds of sources you suggest may answer your question are not readily available to the public. Otus's on-line interviews are generally more focused on being a TSR insider and his later life as an artist (he only worked for TSR for 2-3 years) than on the specifics of any single work of art.

Comment: +1 But a few things: (1) I am not assuming Otus had or did not have access to any module design info: this was why I asked ;), (2) I am not asking only for online sources, (3) some members of the RPG.SE community have in-person or correspondence relationships with game designers, producers, and artists, and may be able to productively shed light. I generally do not assume that published games are the only source of information about any given publication.

Comment: Ah. Well I do hope someone who knows or has contact with Otus weighs in. That would be extremely interesting!